# Сдвигается java.sql.Date после сериализации

Tags: java, дата, serializable

Сразу вопрос: почему дата (java.sql.Date) может на одном устройстве записаться, как (пример) 2022-08-24, а на другом прочитаться, как 2022-08-23? Т.е. "сдвинуться назад" при использовании файла с сериализованным объектом?

Суть: есть небольшое приложение в формате клиент-сервер. Клиент парсит текстовый файл, разбирает на необходимые параметры и один из них - дата. После чего дату записывает в поле класса `Cheque`:

```
    if (flagToParseDate && line.substring(0, 10).contains(Integer.toString(actualYear))){
        cheque.setChequeDate(line.substring(0, 10));
        return cheque;
    }
```

```
    public void setChequeDate(String stringDate){
        this.chequeDate = Date.valueOf(stringDate.replace(".", "-")); // Date принимает формат "yyyy-MM-dd"
    }
```

Каждый объект класса `Cheque` пишется в `ArrayList<Cheque>`:

```
    while ((cheque = parser.parseChequeFromFile(reader)) != null){
        this.listOfCheques.add(cheque);
    }
```

И после этого сериализуется объект класса `ListOfCheques` (в его поле и есть список с объектами `Cheque`):

```
    public static String serializeListOfCheques(ListOfCheques list, String filePath, String fileName){
        try (ObjectOutputStream outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(filePath + fileName))) {
            outStream.writeObject(list);
            return fileName;              // возвращает String fileName - потом это имя сообщается серверу,
                                          // перед отправкой самого файла с объектом. 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

... и после этого мы восстанавливаем файл у себя на сервере:

```
    public static ListOfCheques restoreListOfChequesFromFile(String fileName){
        try (ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(
                new FileInputStream(fileName))) {
            return (ListOfCheques) inStream.readObject(); // восстановили и вернули объект
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

и вот с некоторыми файлами возникает проблема при их чтении - дата "сдвигается назад".
Например, если попробовать прочитать и вывести данные так (тестовая программа):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListOfCheques listObject = restoreListOfChequesFromFile("C:\\Server\\_1179_2022-08-25_List.out");
        ArrayList<Cheque> listList = listObject.getListOfCheques();
        for (Cheque cheque :
                listList) {
            System.out.println(cheque.getPointNumber() + ", " + cheque.getChequeNumber() + ", " + Date.valueOf(cheque.getChequeDateString()) + ", " + cheque.getFlagIsPrinted());
        }

    }
```

то вывод программы будет:

```
1179, 138475, 2022-08-23, true
1179, 138476, 2022-08-23, true
1179, 138478, 2022-08-23, true
1179, 138479, 2022-08-23, true
```

хотя, если ресторить тот же файл не на сервере, а на клиенте, то все будет хорошо, в логе увидим:

```
1179, 138475, 2022-08-24, true
1179, 138476, 2022-08-24, true
1179, 138478, 2022-08-24, true
1179, 138479, 2022-08-24, true
```

P.S. "некоторые объекты" - имеется ввиду, что из 170-200 клиентов подобное происходит с ~10.

jre стоит одной и той же версии.

На некоторых из 10 - другой часовой пояс, на час вперед, но дата выставлена в ОС корректная.

Если слать стрингом, а потом на сервере делать `Date.valueOf()`, то все ок. Но кажется верным сделать это на клиенте, т.к. потом серверу с каждого клиента собирать по 70-100 строк и апдейтить их в базе данных. И если для каждой строки еще и добавить преобразование из String в Date, то работа сильно замедлится, а к серверу подвязан пул соединений и держать при этом коннект было бы странно, наверное...

**Итого:** если кто-то знает, какой нюанс в работе с Date я не учитываю, подскажите, пожалуйста. Просто гуглинг не привел к ответу...

Comment: @Akina пошел снимать этот тег после первого же предложения. 
Но вообще, место ему есть - это связано с тем, чем является объект класса java.sql.Date (в комментарии выше - опечатка) и как обрабатывается дата в sql запросах методами Java.

Comment: *как обрабатывается дата в sql запросах методами Java* Обмен с SQL сервером в обе стороны выполняется обычно в текстовом виде (и редко-редко встречается бинарная строка - причём только для значений). Так что Java или используемый в ней метод однозначно преобразуют значение даты в строковое. Сами. И почему-то некорректно. Я бы предложил сделать самое-самое минимальное модельное приложение и возиться с ним.

Comment: О, про преобразование на при обмене с SQL сервером не знал, спасибо большое. Понял Вашу мысль. Я же имел ввиду, что Java требует от нас при выполнении запроса преобразовать данные к конкретному типу, который будет соответствовать тому, что есть в БД. Если точнее, то сам драйвер JDBC этого требует.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы посмотрите реализацию метода writeObject(), которая пришла из класса родителя java.util.Date, то увидите, что сериализуется некая переменная long fastTime, которая является по сути timestamp на 0 часов и 0 минут требуемой даты. Т.е. если сериализовать этот timestamp на машине с +5:00 и десереализовать на машине с +4:00, то дата будет считаться как 23 часа 00 минут предыдущего дня, после чего часы с минутам отбрасываются и остаётся предыдущий день.

Comment: спасибо за пояснение! 
Про "нормализацию" видел в описании класса java.sql.Date, но либо в перевод не смог до конца, либо не придал этому значения. С полем fastTime стало все яснее, спасибо Вам большое. 
Тогда остается либо хранить дату в формате String, либо в классе Cheque писать условное поле GMT и учитывать его при чтении даты?..

Comment: Я бы выбрал более современные форматы: OffsetDateTime/ZonedDateTime. Ну а String это универсальный солдат)

Comment: понял, принял, ушел осознавать.)) еще раз спасибо!) Будем смотреть на то, что куда лучше преобразовывать, на выходе ведь при формировании PreparedStatement придется использовать sql.Date.. :(